# Calculating Total Harmonic Distortion using only the first harmonic

Tags: distortion, harmonics

I have an assignment for a class where I have to calculate the thd of a signal using MATLAB.

I think I have a pretty good understanding of how this should be done, however, my professor instructed that we use only the first harmonic to calculate the thd.

Maybe my understanding is bad, but I thought the thd was calculated using the first harmonic (fundamental frequency) in relation to the magnitudes of the (other) harmonics. I have looked everywhere online and have not found anyways to calculate thd using only the first harmonic.

I have added the specific assignment phrasing below.

> A  .mat  file  is  given  with  this  project  that  contains  one  period  of  a  periodic  signal. Use  the formulas of the exponential Fourier series and the definition of the total harmonic distortion (Audio engineer’s formula) to calculate the total harmonic distortion of the given signal.In your calculations, you have to just find thefirst harmonic. You need to manipulate the THD formula and represent it as a function of only the first harmonic.

Upon emailing my teacher to clarify if he wanted the thd with respect to the first "additional" harmonic he said he meant fundamental frequency when he said first harmonic.

Comment: Your professor probably means the first harmonic AFTER the fundamental.  The fundamental isn't a harmonic. A harmonic is defined as an integer (whole number) multiple of the fundamental frequency.

Comment: Thats exactly what i thought as well. I emailed him to clarify what he meant, and he said he meant the fundamental frequency

Comment: so then your professor uses *very* uncommon vocabulary. the first harmonic is a harmonic, not the fundamental; but anyways, I'm just mentally removing the words "first harmonic" from your question and replacing them with "fundamental", because you (and your professor) agree it's the fundamental, right?

Comment: I went ahead and edited your question to use "fundamental frequency", because that's what you confirm is meant (and unlike "first harmonic", it's not debatable terminology).

Comment: I'm guessing there's still some confusion here in terminology or communication, but if not, then the calculation becomes trivial.  A fundamental is a pure sinusoid, so what's the THD of that?  MATLAB not needed.

Comment: thank you for your responses. I have added the specific instructions from my teacher because maybe i have misunderstood what he wants. He definitely wants us to use MATLAB.

Comment: since using only the fundamental frequency does not make sense to me given what he wants, I think i have maybe misinterpreted what he exactly wants us to do.

Comment: I think your professor might be saying that he only cares about the THD introduced by the first harmonic (all relative to the fundamental, of course). i.e. Brick wall filter the frequency spectrum of your signal to just be the fundamental and first harmonic, and find the THD of the waveform. Ignore frequencies above the first harmonic.

Comment: Ah, that might be a valid interpretation, too, @Toor, but why call it **total** harmonic distortion, then?

Comment: Because language and maybe the prof just wants the students to know that this is the process to calculate THD but he doesn't want to be tedious and therefore accepts a truncated form of the work.

Comment: yeah, makes sense. edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @hackedhacker77 I reverted my replacement of "first harmonic" based on this comment chain. Makes more sense now!

Comment: thank you for your replies, I am still not completely sure what I will submit, but you guys have definitely given me some options to think about

Comment: @Toor I understand what you mean, but wouldnt that, by his definition, be using the second harmonic?

Comment: @Toor, i completely understand where youre coming from because that was my exact thought process as well, but when i emailed my professor to clarify he said that the fundamental frequency and first harmonic are the same

Comment: I think most of us are wrong here. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic. When I have been saying harmonic (and everyone else here), what we really means is the overtone. I think you'll find many others speak like this too. So the first spike on the spectrum, higher than, but closest to the fundamental is the first overtone. Harmonic refers specifically to multiples of the fundamental so the 1st harmonic is indeed the fundamental while the 2nd harmonic is double that (and may not be present in the spectrum of the signal like a 1Hz square wave which is 1Hz, 3Hz,53Hz, etc.)

Comment: You know what? That makes sense now when they square waves are made of only odd harmonics. I never gave it much though since I already knew what it meant. It wouldn't make sense for 3Hz to be the 2nd harmonic AND an odd harmonic at the same time.

Comment: In my textbooks, the harmonic at frequency \$nf_0\$ was the *n*th harmonic. That means the fundamental and the "first harmonic" are two ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: I remember this well because I had assumed once that the first harmonic was at \$2f_0\$ and got accused of cheating because I got the same wrong answer as other people who made the same terminology error.

Comment: @The Photon Thank you for your reply, given the instructions from my professor do you have an idea about what method he wishes for us to use?

Comment: @hackedhacker77, I don't know the "audio engineer's formula". Can you include that formula in the question? (Along with whatever you were taught are the preconditions for using the formula)

Comment: I wish I could answer that... I couldnt find any information in my textbook or online to clarify this. I have been hesitant to email my professor more, given his hard attitude, but I shoud just bite the bullet.

Comment: If you plan to wing it, outline your entire interpretation of the problem before the solution. Or you can ask the TA, especially the one marking your assignment.

Comment: @Toor Good suggestion, this is due tomorrow, so if I dont hear back from my teacher, I will do that. Hopefully, even if I get the problem wrong, this will get me partial credit. I had asked a student who had taken the professor before and he mentioned he got an F on this assignment, with no answers given by the professor.

Comment: Works for exams too, BTW.

Comment: Regardless whether or not this works out for me, this is my first experience with this site, and I would like to thank everyone who takes time out of their day to help me out, I really appreciate it. I didnt think I would get this much of a response

Comment: also, for the people who provided answers, unfortunately given my new account, i cant upvote you, sorry

Comment: @Toor In my professor's response, hes says he does not mean only use the fundamental harmonic, he just wants the formula to be rearranged so it only has the power of the fundamental frequency. Still not quite sure what he means by this. Any thoughts?

Comment: "In your calculations, you have to just find the first harmonic." This part of of the makes ZERO sense to me. But "rearranged" and "You need to manipulate the THD formula and represent it as a function of only the first harmonic." tells me he just wants the equation put in terms of only the fundamental frequency, not every other frequency.

Answer (score 2):

I'm rolling this up into an answer since it is important. Using a 1Hz square wave as an example, the frequency components are 1Hz, 3Hz, 5Hz, 7Hz, 9Hz, etc... all the way up to infinite.

**Fundamental**: 1Hz, by any definition. The lowest frequency. The period of the waveform.

**Harmonic**: The technically accurate definition for harmonic is an integer multiple of the fundamental. Therefore, the nth harmonic is n times the fundamental frequency. In the example, 3Hz is the third harmonic and 1Hz is the first harmonic (aka the fundamental).

However, you will find many engineers use "harmonic" when they mean to say overtone.

**Overtone**: An overtone refers to the most prominent frequency components in the spectrum of a signal in numerical sequence above the and NOT including the fundamental. Therefore, in the example, the first overtone is 3Hz, and the second overtone is 5Hz. 1Hz, the fundamental frequency, is not an overtone at all.

To make thing worse, you can also find engineers using both the technically correct, and commonly understood but incorrect definitions of "harmonic"  where the meaning might changes based on context since we already know what we're talking about. For example, I say square waves are made up of only odd harmonics (technically correct), but then I might absentmindedly say that 3Hz is the first harmonic in in a 1Hz square wave, when I really should be saying first overtone or third harmonic.

For the record, I have never heard "overtone" used in any engineering class of mine. Ever. The only reason I know of it is from music classes. It needs to be a thing because those musicians have been talking about frequencies far longer than we have. They already figured it out.

Comment: @hackedhacker77 Now that I've said all that, you need to find out from your prof if he literally wants you to use only the fundamental/1st harmonic when calculating THD and pretend like no other frequency components exist...which would give a trivial answer of zero, or if he means for you take just the fundamental component as the only frequency component in your pristine signal, using that as a reference, and treating all other frequency components as noise/distortion.

Comment: Thank you. Given this information and given what the professor has requested, is there a method that you would suggest using?

Comment: I hadnt read your comment yet before responding. I think that is probably the best suggestion. My professor was very curt in my previous clarification email, so i was hesitant on sending another, but i should get clarification

Comment: Just say that if you ONLY use the 1st harmonic/fundamental in the THD calculations, wouldn't the THD = 0 since there are no other frequency components being used in the calculation? Which frequencies should you treat as the pristine signal and which are the distortion and noise?

Answer (score 1):

> contains one period of a periodic signal.

Means that you know the period, let's call it \$N\$, and thus, the frequency \$f=\frac1N\$, of your fundamental.

You know that all the higher-order harmonics have frequencies that are multiples of that frequency.

Now, if you *had* the power of the fundamental signal only, you could simply subtract that power from the total signal power (which is really just the sum of the magnitude squares of your signal), and had the power in the noise + harmonics. If noise is absent, you'd only have the total harmonic power, and divided by the signal power that becomes your THD.

So, filter out with a low pass filter that cuts off between \$f\$ and \$2f\$, and calculate energy before and after. Done!

---

With @Toor's comment:

Yeah, what your professor might mean (contrary to her/him using **total** harmonic distortion) is that for the distortion calculation, you should only use the fundamental relative to the first harmonic; so, same idea: filter with a cutoff after \$2f\$, and do your THD calculations on that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is a little bit what I had initially thought, but wouldnt using the total signal power be "using" the other harmonics in my calculation?

Comment: hence the filtering.